# Sed - merge two lines based on a pattern in second line

Tags: sed

I'm working on a data dump from a phone and need to get a chat file re-formatted

```
Person1   my son will be there shortly
5/3/2018 6:02:31 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   OK. Tell him to call when he's here
5/3/2018 6:03:33 PM(UTC+0)
Person1   Ok
5/3/2018 6:03:41 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   You forgot your charger
5/3/2018 8:43:20 PM(UTC+0)
```

I need to change to this (the chat and the timestamp are separated by a tab):

```
Person1   my son will be there shortly   5/3/2018 6:02:31 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   OK. Tell him to call when he's here   5/3/2018 6:03:33 PM(UTC+0)
Person1   Ok   5/3/2018 6:03:41 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   You forgot your charger  5/3/2018 8:43:20 PM(UTC+0)
```

I've been trying to merge a line that contains "UTC" with the PREVIOUS line, but so far the best I've gotten is:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n.*UTC/\t/;ta' -e 'P;D' temp.txt > temp2.txt
```

And the results are these:

```
Person1   my son will be there shortly   +0)
Person2   OK. Tell him to call when he's here   +0)
Person1   Ok   5/3/2018 +0)
Person2   You forgot your charger  +0)
```

The reason I want to use "UTC" as the pattern is that there are other extraneous lines in the file that are NOT timestamps (e.g. multi-line chat entries, information about attachments, etc.). "UTC" is the only pattern that's unique to timestamps.

Comment: So you want each "UTC" line merged with the previous line, is that it?

Comment: Yes, Beta. Any line that contains UTC must be merged with the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```sh
$ sed 'N;/\n.*UTC/s/\n/\t/;P;D' infile
Person1   my son will be there shortly  5/3/2018 6:02:31 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   OK. Tell him to call when he's here   5/3/2018 6:03:33 PM(UTC+0)
Person1   Ok    5/3/2018 6:03:41 PM(UTC+0)
Person2   You forgot your charger       5/3/2018 8:43:20 PM(UTC+0)
```

`N;P;D` creates a moving two-line window; the command `/\n.*UTC/s/\n/\t/` says "if the pattern space has `UTC` on the second line, substitute the newline with a tab".

Comment: Thank you. Now I'll go back to the documentation to better understand how this works. (And hopefully you'll see this before it's deleted by tptb.)

Comment: @alex_223 If you have a recent GNU sed, you can run in debug mode (`--debug`) to see what exactly is happening. I find it very instructive.

Comment: @benjamin-w: Thanks for your useful answer. I couldn't find what N;P;D means. Can you please explain it. Maybe it means (Next (line); Print; Delete)

Comment: @ni_hao The commands are documented in the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-D-_0028delete-first-line_0029-command), and there's an [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#tail) for a sliding window. `N` appends a line to the pattern space, `P` prints the first line in the pattern space, and `D` deletes the first line in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample is representative of a regularly structured file and you simply need to merge every other line with the previous line, the script can be simplified significantly.

I prefer Awk for legibility and maintainability:

```
awk 'NR%2 { printf "%s\t", $0; next } 1' file >newfile
```

In some more detail, NR is the current line number (or more properly record number; by default Awk splits records on newlines) and `%` is the mathematical modulo operator. The expression evaluates to non-zero (true) on even-numbered lines, and so we print those with a tab instead of a newline. The `next` statement terminates the script for this input line and fetches the next line and starts over, just like the `n`/`N` command in `sed`. Finally, the lone `1` is true for every line which falls through to here, causing it to be printed verbatim.

Comment: This won't work in my case. As I indicated, not all the file is like the excerpt I presented, and there are multi-line chat entries, as well as other lines that break the pattern. But thank you nonetheless.